# Tokenize dataframe column and create new dataframe for result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({'category': [1,2,1], 'names' : ['ab c', 's', 'dm ab aaa']})

category   names
0   1      ab c
1   2      s
2   1      dm ab aaa
```

Really I need to find all unique tokens(separated by space) in names column, assign corresponding category and create new datafrane as you can see below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'category' : [1, 1,2,1,1,1], 'names' : ['ab', 'c', 's', 'dm', 'ab', 'aaa']})

category   names
0   1      ab
1   1      c
2   2      s
3   1      dm
4   1      ab
5   1      aaa
```

Please help me and how to do it the best way...

Comment: `df[['category']].join(df['names'].str.split().explode())` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `names` column first and then `explode` it:

```
df.assign(names = df.names.str.split()).explode('names')

#   category names
#0         1    ab
#0         1     c
#1         2     s
#2         1    dm
#2         1    ab
#2         1   aaa
```

If you need to reset index (from @KRKirov's comment):

```
df.assign(names = df.names.str.split()).explode('names').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: +1. df.assign(names = df.names.str.split()).explode('names').reset_index(drop=True)
might be better.